# Need to Convert Json to DataFrame in Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, parsing, dataframe

Here is the **JSON** that needs to be converted

```
{
  "name": "Jon",
    "tags":[
            {
                "1": "San Jose",
                "2": "California",
                "3": 1987
            },
            {   
                "1": "University Ave",
                "2": "Princeton",
                "3": 1990
            }
    ]
}
```

It needs to be converted into a `DataFrame`, like this one

```
Name  1               2            3
Jon   SanJose         California   1987
Jon   Univesity Ave   Princeton    1990
```

Can anyone help me getting this riddle done. Thank you!!

Comment: Which JSON library are you using? What have you tried so far? Show us some code that doesn't work so we can where you're going off track.

Comment: When you say _"dataframe"_ do you mean `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` from **Spark**? If so, 1. add the `apache-spark` tag, 2. Spark support that out of the box, just reading the basic tutorials or giving a quick search in google will give you the answer - if not, just ignore this comment and concentrate in jwvh's comment.

Comment: I am using json4s library are those the correct imports or do I have to use jacksons.
....
`import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonParser

val rdd = sqlContext.read.json("file path").toDF ("Name","1","2","3")`
....
to read the json file but it didn't get me the output while I am looking for. Do you I have use some schema to read it and then make it to Dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, [**Spark** supports **JSON** *paring* out of the box](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html) - you do not need any external library.

**Spark**, will automatically infer the *schema* of your file, but it will no flatten the data automatically...
You will need to do that on your program.

Here is a simple example of how you could do that using a *typed* `Dataset`.
*(Note: The JSON file should contain one document per line, as stated in the documentation)*.
*(Also, note that I renamed the fields to `a`, `b` & `c` so they are valid **Scala** identifiers)*.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, Encoder}

final case class Nested(name: String, tags: List[Tag])
final case class Tag(a: String, b: String, c: Int)
final case class Flattened(name: String, a: String, b: String, c: Int)

val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val nestedEncoder: Encoder[Nested] = implicitly
val nestedSchema = nestedEncoder.schema

val nestedDS =
  spark
    .read
    .option(key = "charset", value = "UTF-8")
    .schema(nestedSchema)
    .json(path = "path")
    .as[Nested](nestedEncoder)

val flattenedDS = for {
  nested <- nestedDS
  tag <- nested.tags
} yield Flattened(nested.name, tag.a, tag.b, tag.c)
// flattenedDS: Dataset[Flattened] = [name: string, a: string, b: string, c: integer]

flattenedDS.printSchema()
// root
//  |-- name: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- a: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- b: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- c: integer (nullable = false)

flattenedDS.show()
// +----+--------------+----------+----+
// |name|             a|         b|   c|
// +----+--------------+----------+----+
// | Jon|      San Jose|California|1987|
// | Jon|University Ave| Princeton|1990|
// +----+--------------+----------+----+
```

Comment: Do not need all on 1 line.

Comment: @thebluephantom Can you elaborate please?, I do not quite understand. - If you mean the `Encoder`, I do need it in the `val nestedEncoder: Encoder[Nested] = implicitly` line.

Comment: Not sure I follow.

Comment: @thebluephantom Sorry, neither do I. Let's just start again - you said _"Do not need all on 1 line"_, I do not understand what you mean with that, could you please explain me?

Comment: what if I have spark 1.6, and how can I use sqlContext.read instead of spark.read ?

Comment: Because I am getting this error while I was compiling 
`object SparkSession is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql`

Comment: @R7777777 Well, looking at the [**documentation**](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets), it seems you only need to do `val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)` instead & use _sqlContext_ everywhere _spark_ was used. However, I have never used **Spark** 1.6 so, it may be other silly differences, but in general it should work.